# i got error 500 on production when i read filefield in django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

hello everyone please help me
i have recently maked a  website  but i got  500 error when i put it in production
but strangly all is working well in my computer
i am trying to read the buffer of a filefield inside a model and itson local but not in production

```
class post(models.Model):
titre=models.CharField(unique=True,null=True,max_length=100)
description=models.TextField(null=True,blank=True,max_length=400)
T=models.CharField(default="image",blank=True,max_length=50)
image=models.FileField(null=True)
cat=models.ForeignKey(categorie,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
datepost=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,blank=True)
user=models.ForeignKey(myuser,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
vue=models.IntegerField(default=0,blank=True)
def __str__(self):
    return self.titre

def save(self, *args ,**kwargs):
    #cette partie permet de generer un identifiant unique
    f=self.image.readline()
    mime=magic.from_buffer(f,mime=True)
    if "video" in mime :
        self.T="short"
    super(post,self).save(*args,**kwargs)
```

sorry for my english and thank you for your help

Comment: You need to post the stacktrace (error output).  If you have access to the logs on the server, you might be able to see the error output.  Worst case, you can change the `settings.py` file's `DEBUG=True` in production to see the output of the error in the browser window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got its not the read method which have a problem
but i'm using cloudinary and cloudinary checks mimes types of files from buffer
so when i use read method the cursor is moved  after the file signature

i've used  file.seek(0) to resolve my problem

```
File=self.cleaned_data["image"] 
    mime=magic.from_buffer(File.open("rb").read(1000),mime=True)
    File.seek(0)
```

sorry  for my bad english ;)